# optimal zoom distance to show all polyLines at map load

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map with multiple polyLines.
I want a function that I can send a group of polylines to, and it return the tightest possible zoom range to show the lines entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the points you want visible to an empty [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object (with .extend()) then run .fitBounds() on the resulting bounds.

All the points you want visible are all the vertices of all the polylines.